# Why is saving data from an API to CSV faster than uploading it to MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, performance, api, csv, data-collection

My question revolves around understanding the following two procedures (particularly performance and code logic) that I used to collect trade data from the US Census Bureau API. I already collected the data but I ended up writing two different ways of requesting and saving the data for which my questions pertain to.

Summary of my final questions comes at the bottom.

#### First way: npm request and mongodb to save the data

I limited my procedure using tiny-async-pool (sets concurrency of a certain function to perform) to not try to request too much at once or receive a timeout or overload my database with queries. Simply put, the bottleneck I was facing was the database since the API requests returned rather quickly (depending on body size 1-15 secs), but to save each array item (return data was nested array, sometimes from a few hundred items to over one hundred thousand items with max 10 values in each array) to its own mongodb document ranged from 100 ms to 700 ms. To save time from potential errors and not redoing the same queries, I also performed a check in my database before making the query to see if the query was already complete. The end result was that I did not follow this method since it was very error prone and susceptible to timeouts if the data was very large (I even set the timeout to 10 minutes in request options).

#### Second way: npm request and save data to csv

I used the same approach as the first method for the requests and concurrency, however I saved each query to its own csv file. In case of errors and not redoing successful queries I also did a check to see if the file already existed and if so skipped that query. This approach was error free, I ran it and after a few hours was able to have all the data saved. To write to csv was insanely fast, much more so than using mongodb.

#### Final summary and questions

My end goal was to get the data in the easiest manner possible. I used javascript because that's where I learned api requests and async operations, even though I will do most of my data analysis with python and pandas. I first tried the database method mostly because I thought it was the right way and I wanted to improve my database CRUD skills. After countless hours of refactoring code and trying new techniques I still could not get it to work properly. I resorted to the csv method which was a) much less code to write, b) less checks, c) faster, and d) more reliable.

My final questions are these:

- Why was the csv approach better than the database approach? Any counter arguments or different approaches you would have used?
- How do you handle bottlenecks and concurrency in your applications with regards to APIs and database operations? Do your techniques vary in production environments from personal use cases (in my case I just needed the data and a few hours of waiting was fine)?
- Would you have used a different programming language or different package/module for this data collection procedure?

Comment: CSV was faster because you did a much simpler thing there. You put the whole blob into a file and that's it. No integrity checks, no indexes, nothing. For all you know the files weren't even written properly. Whereas with mongo you send each array item as a separate document (also waiting on write completion, I assume?). Writing the whole response into the same document would have improved mongo performance. Or batching.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to give your input. Your two comments led me to do a little more research and I found the following: 
Mongoose lets you define a schema for arrays called primitive arrays. Additionally there is a mongoose-int32 plugin for reducing size of the dtype.
I also just found the bulkWrite method which would help a ton with multiple uploads at once.